# Need for arml tag for future

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

Right now the arml(augmented reality markup language) is a growing technology and now there is a need to create tags regarding arml here.

As normally most people develop these types of applications through wikitude sdk and vuforia sdk, people may have queries regarding it.

Although the respected forums provide neccessary information,while developing people may have queries, so why can't we create a [arml](/questions/tagged/arml) and related tags.

Since its an upcoming technology and implemented why can't we add it and help the users to explore arml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we please have the \[foo\] tag on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have a question that already exists which the tag *should* be applied to, you can't "create" a tag.

That said, if you find any, then you should tag it with [arml](/questions/tagged/arml) (I'd prefer something more verbose, really) or make a request (in comments, or to a mod) to have it tagged with that.

Answer (score 3):

Questions are retagged all the time, so there is no need to reserve a tag for the future. It is always there when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't need this tag yet.

We already have the [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) tag, which is a perfectly suitable tag to watch for people interested in the general topic.  There are already tags for [wikitude](/questions/tagged/wikitude) and [qcar-sdk](/questions/tagged/qcar-sdk) (the Qualcomm Vuforia thing).  Together these tags present enough information for people interested in the topic.  It seems that *nobody* has adopted ARML outside of these two product SDKs.  Given that it was their idea to begin with (or so says a few minutes of research on the internets), then that isn't too surprising.